# Best way to access fuel efficiency data during operation?

Tags: fuel-consumption, diagnostics

I'm looking for ways to track real-time fuel efficiency data while driving, using an app on my phone. Will a Bluetooth OBD adapter generally allow me to do this?

Comment: I always wondered how the engine guys could calculate fuel efficiency so well.  So it seems fuel injectors are VERY reliable on how much fuel they deliver at every pulse.  That's how to set fuel air ratio.  And knowing how many pulses have gone by (i.e. Exactly how much fuel is being injected) and how far you've traveled in a given time gives them the ability to EXACTLY determine instant fuel economy.

Comment: @zipzit - The term you are looking for with the fuel injectors is *pulse width*, and yes it's very accurate as to how much fuel is delivered. The other parts of the equation is the fuel pressure at the rail where the injector gets it's fuel supply from and the calibrated amount of fuel flow from the given injector. Increasing your fuel pressure at the rail will allow you to have more fuel flow through the injector, which can save you buying new injectors if you can safely run the pressure higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the OBD-II port can supply data about average fuel economy and instantaneous fuel economy. There are devices on the market that can be purchased and used for fuel consumption monitoring as well as data delivery on a number of different processes going on in your vehicle.

We're advised to not suggest specific products on this forum as they are very opinion-based. However, a quick google search can provide you with plenty of options to explore. I'm not sure if you already had an app in mind that you wanted to use, but I assume that google can shed some light on that topic as well. Good luck!

Comment: You can make product recommendations in the comments section.

Comment: Search for "ScanGauge" or "UltraGauge" on google.

Comment: You can make product recommendations within the body of the answer if you aren't affiliated with it in any way ... just throw out the non-attribution clause in your answer and you're golden. We all have our favorite products/services/websites for things. If there is no harm, there is no foul.